# Using one Wix Dynamic Page for various entries in the site menu

Tags: velo

I am doing a site in Wix.com so my wife can maintain it without my input. The draft site is live at:

http://www.wingspan.info

IMPORTANT: The wife is not a techie.

Essentially, the site displays our art work in galleries of paintings, etc, filtered by artist.

I have coded one page, then duplicated that to create the galleries and filter the WixDataQuery according to Andrew or Helen and Categories like Painting, Drawing, Sculpture, iPad Art, etc. Also, where we have exhibited (Exhibitions menu) some of our paintings.

All working, but any change to design and I have to change 15 pages...

So, it now strikes me that it would be more efficient to design one dynamic page, and set up the menu to display the different categories, as it is set up in the live site:

[image]

However, I can't find any documentation that shows how to use just the one dynamic page rather than my coded page duplicated to produce 12 different pages. Not clever...

Any suggestions / tutorials where I can find how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to add the Content Manager to your site if you haven't already, and then set up a collection with all of your data in it. One row per eventual "page" that you want.

Next, you can take the page you already designed and convert it to a dynamic page. It will then have a dataset on the page which you need to connect to various elements on the page through their connect buttons.

Finally, you'll need to edit your menu to point to the various instances of your dynamic page instead of the regular pages you have them pointing to now.

You can read all about how dynamic pages work [here](https://learn.wix.com/en/lessons/content-manager-101) and [here](https://support.wix.com/en/content-manager/dynamic-pages).

Comment: Thanks, but my situation is more complex. For example, I would have to use what in Velo is "contains" on the fields: For example, one piece of artwork could've been in multiple exhibitions. So, in the exhibitions field, you would have "Tate Modern, Tate Britain, National Gallery" indicating exhibitions in each of these museums (dream on...). I think I will just leave it as is. There seems to be no way to get the urls doing what I need.

Comment: However, for most of the galleries, I could have urls along the lines of: wingspan.info/{artist}/{category} that would give a url of say: wingspan.info/andrew/painting. So that would reduce some of the duplication. But I don't see a way out where you need to query the collection using a "contains" clause.

Comment: If you can give us a more complete picture of the types of URLs you want and what you want to show up on those pages, maybe someone here can come up with an answer for you.